# Convert progressive JPEG to baseline JPEG

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, jpeg, image-compression

I'm getting a user profile image from Azure AD using below graph api. But when i'm trying to hit the api using POSTMAN tool its giving me a PJPEG image and then i'm not able to get the actual image. So is there any way i can get the jpeg image or convert that pjpeg bytes to base64 and then to image.

Please help.

[Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BUseremailid%7D/photo/$value).

Comment: what have you tried so far.it looks like you are trying to do a lot with postman. what are the errors you getting

Comment: Could you please share more detailed steps or screenshots? Based on my test, I can just get normal jpeg file with Postman. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw4eX.png)

Comment: @Prany, I'm not getting errors, when i'm trying to access graph api mentioned above i'm getting 200 response with a encoded image value whose content type is pjpeg so i'm unable to convert it to base64 and get original image

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal It says Access token is empty, guess you're not sending oauth. please share more deatiled steps as Jack mentioned

Comment: i'm sending the auth token in headers, as i mentioned i'm getting response also but its a pjpeg response and i want jpeg response, because in AD images are stored in jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update user photo with postman, please refer to the following steps

1. Register Azure AD application
2. Configure API permissions
   [image]
3. Get access token in Postman
   [image]
   [image]
4. update photo. My test [pjpeg](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2upC1TdCcZhD9R8_S70QHtBP4H) file

```
PUT PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
Content-type: image/pjpeg

Body: Binary data for the image
```

[image]

4. Check

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

[image]

Comment: I dont want to update, i just want to read the photo and issue is while reading i'm getting response in pjpeg while i want in jpeg.

Comment: Have you tried to add ```content-type: image/jpeg```?